# Need i use Server Rending App on my project?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

in this moment i follow the course " The Complete Junior to Senior Web Developer Roadmap" on Udemy, and i’m on the section about Server Side Rending, now i thinked but i need to do on my App, let me explain, i follow this course and when i learn a thing i use on my Application :

https://razeft.herokuapp.com/

but now i don’t know if use Server Side Rendering this, because i do this already:
https://github.com/AlexGioffre/Razeft

so i really need the Server Side Rending on this project?

Answer (score 0):

Using SSR depends on the type of project you are building, if your app needs to have a Good SEO You need to go with SSR otherwise go with Client side rendering